# Should I have one big angular file for my entire website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a website that will have facebook-ish features (friends and what not) along with a marketplace and some forums. I've decided to use bootstrap as I'm not a good designer and rather than using Jquery I've come across a replacement for their plugins written in angular (UI bootstrap is the name).

Should I just have one giant angular file for my entire website, aka the plugins for UI one and add whatever else I need to do that, or should I load in two different files? One will be the pre-written plugins and the other one will be the web app needed for that page (for example having the marketplace web app in its own file and include both of them on the same page).

This is my first website so I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible, thanks for the input!

Comment: much easier grouping features together and using build tools like gulp or grunt to combine files

Comment: +1 for gulp or grunt.  Also make multiple files.  A great style guide I like to follow: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: so if im understanding this correctly make different files for different things and then use gulp or grunt to compile them into one? ive heard of gulp and grunt but havent actually used either, any good references to learn this tech quickly as im in a bit of a time squeeze? also i use webstorm and will have to learn node as i go along, would it be the same principle (use one of those two or is backend completely different in this regard)?

Comment: numerous MEAN stacks around that will give you a starter app with both node and angular already running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do one for the scripts that you wrote and another for the vendor scripts.

But if you are starting new to gulp or grunt you should really consider using a scaffolding tool such as [yeoman](http://yeoman.io). If you use [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) you will see some good examples for both angular and grunt, as well as node.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not, you should only have one angular component per file. Working with a scaffolding tool such as [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) or [Slush](http://slushjs.github.io/#/) will make this much easier.

Additionally, I would recommend reading some of the AngularJS styleguides out there. [John Papa's guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and [Todd Motto's guide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) are good places to start. [Here's a full list of AngularJS resources to get you started.](https://github.com/JonathanZWhite/AngularJS-Resources) Good luck!